# Problem with Radium while updating react from 15.4.1 to 16.8.6

Tags: css, reactjs, radium

While I am updating my React app from version 15.4.1 to React 16.8.6 I get the error 
`Cannot read property 'object' of undefined at Object../node_modules/radium/lib/components`
How do i fix this error

```
 var Style = _react2.default.createClass({
  28 |   displayName: 'Style',
  29 |   propTypes: {
> 30 |     radiumConfig: _react.PropTypes.object,
  31 |     rules: _react.PropTypes.object,
  32 |     scopeSelector: _react.PropTypes.string
  33 |   },
```

this is what i get on my browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `PropTypes` are no longer available in React v16. You may need to update to a later version of Radium as the library has been updated to use the `prop-types` package from npm.

You can see the radium change log [here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0191-may-17-2017)